# What issues should be addressed in meta questions with FAQ tag?

Tags: discussion

Compared to other Stack Exchange website, we do not have many questions under the [FAQ tag](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) (only 3 posts, compared to 17 FAQ posts on [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) or [Mathematics.SX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)). These questions really help users (newly registered or older ones) to get more familiar with site policies and disciplines.

What are the characteristics of a good FAQ post? What issues do we need to be covered on this website as FAQ? What topics are not covered in the current FAQ posts? Do we need a wiki-type answer to this question as a *to-do list* of topics which need to be answered in form of FAQ? Or kind of tag on meta for posts which propose a FAQ issue?

Also, I think that it does worth if users find some good questions in meta; (if these questions have minimum characteristics of a FAQ post) propose them to be tagged with such FAQ tag to make them easier to be found by other users.

As an instance, Mathematics.SX has a tag on its meta under which users can propose FAQ topics called [faq-proposed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

Answer (score 4):

Well... what Questions actually get Asked here Frequently?

I think your heart is in the right place here, but you're probably overthinking things a bit. FAQ entries can be generated on an as-needed basis, just like tags are, and things seem to be running just fine around here at the moment. It doesn't seem to me like actively looking for FAQ entries to write would be a particularly good use of anyone's time right now.

As you may know, a moderator is needed to apply the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag, but there's nothing special about the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag; its usage is just a convention. If and when you (or someone else) do produce a proposed new FAQ entry, it would probably be better to just flag for moderator attention than to use a special tag, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to see answered in the FAQ is the difference between good and bad opinion based questions. I think some questions that seem to be asking about opinions are really asking about academic culture, while others are asking for personal opinions. I think we have covered this in a couple of meta questions already, but having a nice answer would be great